# Executing load test of a WCF service using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying running load tests using JMeter V2.5.1. The WCF service are published in IIS as WCF-CustomIsolated.

If I follow the instructions especified in the URL http://twenty6-jc.blogspot.com/2011/11/performance-and-loading-testing-wcf.html, the requests are sent by the tool, but I obtain the following error code:

```
Response code:415
Response Message:Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.

Cabeceras de respuesta:
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 13:33:17 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0


HTTPSampleResult campos:
ContentType: text/xml
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

The XML message that I have established in the SOAP/XML-RPC textbox is the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xun="http://Xunta.IFRT.Servicios.Firma.ValidarCertificado.Peticion">
   <soap:Header>
   <To soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
https://localhost/ValidarCertificado/ValidarCertificado.svc</To>
</soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <xun:Peticion>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xun:Atributos>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xun:DatosAutorizacion>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:IdentificadorSolicitante>OficinaEadmin</xun:IdentificadorSolicitante>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:TokenPassword>nimdaEanicifO</xun:TokenPassword>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:Motivo>Motivo</xun:Motivo>
               </xun:DatosAutorizacion>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xun:DatosEjecucion>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:IdentificadorSolicitudCliente>1234</xun:IdentificadorSolicitudCliente>
               </xun:DatosEjecucion>
            </xun:Atributos>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xun:MensajeEntrada>
               <xun:TipoPeticion>ObtenerInfoCertificado</xun:TipoPeticion>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xun:Parametros>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:certificado>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</xun:certificado>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xun:modoValidacion>2</xun:modoValidacion>
                  <xun:obtenerInfo>true</xun:obtenerInfo>
               </xun:Parametros>
            </xun:MensajeEntrada>
         </xun:Peticion>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas about this error message?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Try using an [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to specify the correct header (content type : 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8').

Comment: If I apply this change, the tool can test the web service successfully! Thank you very much.